# Flutter text field not allowing input after clearing form fields and setting focus to it

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**Update:** I edited the code to be a minimal reproducible example that you can copy past into a flutter project and immediately run it.

This seems like it might be a Flutter bug, but I thought I'd ask here first before submitting a bug report. I have the form below. The radio button selection defaults to Check Out when the form opens. When the user changes it to the other radio button, the form fields should clear and the focus should be set to the location field and allow input immediately.

When I open the form and select Check In (i.e. the other button), the form switches focus to the location field and lets me enter stuff like normal. However, if I then switch to the Check Out option, the focus still appears to be on the location field but when I try to type stuff nothing shows up. And then when I select Check In again, the same thing happens - it doesn't let me enter anything. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it seems as though requesting focus more than once in a row before typing anything is buggy.

**Form open:**

[image]

**Selecting the Check In option (focus switches to location field and I'm able to start typing immediately):**

[image]

**Selecting the Check Out option (location field clears, cursor still appears on it, but when I type stuff nothing shows up):**

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

enum CheckInOutType { checkIn, checkOut }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  CheckInOutType? selectedCheckInOut = CheckInOutType.checkOut;
  final locController = TextEditingController();
  late FocusNode locFocusNode; // = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); //Run this first
    initialize();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose(); //Run this last
    locFocusNode.dispose();
  }

  void initialize() async {
    locFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  void clearFields() {
    locController.text = '';
    locFocusNode.requestFocus();
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Overflow Inventory'),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: const Text('Check In'),
                    leading: Radio<CheckInOutType>(
                      value: CheckInOutType.checkIn,
                      groupValue: selectedCheckInOut,
                      onChanged: (CheckInOutType? value) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedCheckInOut = value;
                        });
                        clearFields();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: const Text('Check Out'),
                    leading: Radio<CheckInOutType>(
                      value: CheckInOutType.checkOut,
                      groupValue: selectedCheckInOut,
                      onChanged: (CheckInOutType? value) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedCheckInOut = value;
                        });
                        clearFields();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Text('${selectedCheckInOut == CheckInOutType.checkOut ? 'From' : 'To'} Location:', style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700))
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      focusNode: locFocusNode,
                      controller: locController,
                    )
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with Flutter support and the problem was fixed by upgrading Flutter from 3.10 to 3.16 using `flutter upgrade --force`.